# What algorithm can be used to detect gaps between polygons?

Tags: algorithm, go, polygon, computational-geometry

What algorithms are used to find gaps between adjacent polygons (example pictures show 2 adjacent polygons and a shaded 'gap' between them), and is there a common name for this type of operation? Polygons in my input may have coincident vertices, segments, both, or neither. Polygons are represented as ordered lists of points. Adjacent polygons are defined as having at least one coincident point or segment.

I am developing in Go (and have access to the [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) library), but any references to algorithm steps or implementations in common languages would be helpful.

[image: adjacent/intersecting polygons]
[image: adjacent/intersecting polygons with hole shaded]

Comment: What about getting the union of the two shapes and check the union for holes?

Comment: Geos seems to be returning a multipolygon for unions of polygons with adjacent points... but maybe I can try to buffer one of them first.

Comment: And if you don't buffer?

Comment: It returns back two separate polygons as a MULTIPOLYGON.

Comment: I would not have expected that result. Well, if it dissolves the holes, then create the union and subtract the original polygons (as in set difference) and see if anything is left.

Comment: @SirGuy The buffer solution did, in fact, preserve the holes in the resulting polygon. But the two polygons must have crossing segments, rather than only coincident points, for GEOS to return a single polygon from the Union function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please be explicit about what you call a "gap". Your description is not sufficiently formal.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you were looking for, but something like this might get the job done.

Suppose you can calculate a list of all points of intersection p1, p2, …, pk between the perimeters of the two polygons. Let v1, v2, …, vn be the vertices of the first polygon, and w1, w2, …, wm be the vertices of the second polygon.

First, create two ordered collections c1 and c2, where c1 contains p1, p2, …, pk and v1, v2, …, vn, in order (so that if going around the perimeter of the polygon in the clockwise direction, the vertices appear in the list in the order visited), and c2 contains p1, p2, … pk and w1, v2, …, vm ordered in the same way.

Now, between every two adjacent p(i%k) and p((i+1)%k) there is some overlap or gap. This overlap or gap may be degenerate iff the vertices appearing in c1 and c2 between these two points of intersection are the same; in this case, the polygon traced out has area zero and may be discarded. Otherwise, we must see whether the vertices in c1 and c2 appearing between the points of intersection define a gap or an overlap.

If we have an easy/cheap way of testing whether a point is contained within the original polygon, simply choose a point in the space (e.g., the center of the triangle formed by one of the points of intersection and each of the adjacent points in c1 and c2 is guaranteed to be inside the space) and see whether the point is included in either c1 or c2 (it cannot be in one and not the other; why?). If the point is included, then you have an overlap; otherwise, you have a gap.

Indeed, we do have an easy way. If we are going around the first polygon in clockwise order, then if the point identified above (the middle of the triangle so described) is to the right of the line segment formed by the point of intersection and the vertex in c1 adjacent to it, then it's an overlap; otherwise, it's a gap. Alternatively, you can go clockwise around the points in c2 and use the same rule to tell.

To see whether a point is to the left or right of a vector:

1. take the vector (e.g., the point of intersection to the adjacent point in either c1 or c2)
2. take the vector to the candidate point (e.g., the center of the triangle described earlier)
3. Compute the 3-dimensional cross product
4. The sign of the z-coordinate of the resulting vector gives the answer.

In this example:

```
p1, p2, p3 ~ (3.1, 5.5), (3.3, 4), (3.8, 2)
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 ~ (1, 0), (1, 8), (4, 4.5), (2, 3), (3.8, 2)
w1, w2, w3, w4 ~ (4, 1), (3, 5), (4, 9), (9, 5)

c1 ~ (v1, v2, p1, v3, p2, v4, p3=v5)
c2 ~ (w1, p3, p2, w2, p1, w3, w4)

pairs of points of intersection adjacent in c1:
x1 = (p1, p2), x2 = (p2, p3), x3 = (p3, p1)

pairs of points of intersection adjacent in c2:
y1 = (p3, p2), y2 = (p2, p1), y3 = (p1, p3)

triangle for x1 has vertices (p1, v3, w2), middle is
~ ((3.1+4+3)/3, (5.5+4.5+5)/3) = (3.3, 5)

vector from p1 to v3 ~ (0.9, -1)
vector from p1 to middle of triangle ~ (0.2, -0.5)

cross product of p1-v3 x middle of triangle vector:

    +0.9    -1.0    +0.0
    +0.2    -0.5    +0.0
      i       j       k

=> -0.45k

this has a negative sign, so this is an overlap

triangle for x2 has vertices (p2, v4, p3=v5), middle is
~ ((3.3+2+3.8)/3, (4+3+2)/3) = (3, 3)

vector from p2 to v4: (-1.3, -1)
vector from p2 to middle of triangle: (-0.3, -1)

cross product of p2-v4 and middle of triangle vector:

    -1.3    -1.0    +0.0
    -0.3    -1.0    +0.0
      i       j       k

=> 1.3k

this has a positive sign, so this must be a gap
```